# sql calling custom function - tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am doing the following:

```
    Insert into table1 
   (Phone#) values @Phone
```

There is a custom function which will format the phone number. It accepts as input parameter the phone number and returns the formatted version.

I tried the following but not sure it would not work:

```
    Insert into table1 
   (Phone#) values fn_phone(@Phone)
```

It says fn_phone is not a recognized built in function name. Am I doing something wrong on how I am calling fn_phone?

Comment: I was under the assumption that you needed to use parens around the VALUES set.  e.g., INSERT INTO table1 (phone_num) VALUES (dbo.fn_phone(@phone))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use two-part name when you are calling UDF

Try this:

```
Insert into table1  
   (Phone#) select dbo.fn_phone(@Phone)
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Insert into table1 (Phone#) 
SELECT dbo.fn_phone(@Phone) (or whatever schema your function is in)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the function is from "dbo" schema :

```
    Insert into table1 
   (Phone#) values (dbo.fn_phone(@Phone))
```

Comment: The value or values that follow the `VALUES` keyword must also be enclosed in (round) brackets.